# How to mimic pandas' duplicated in polars

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

In this example:

```py
In [6]: pd.Series([1, 2, 2, 3]).duplicated()
Out[6]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool

In [7]: pl.Series([1, 2, 2, 3]).is_duplicated()
Out[7]:
shape: (4,)
Series: '' [bool]
[
        false
        true
        true
        false
]
```

pandas tells me that the second `2` is the duplicated one. However, polars flags both of them as duplicated.

Is there a way to mimic the pandas `duplicated` behaviour here?

Answer (score 3):

Found it, there's `is_first`, that was easy

```py
In [9]: ~pl.Series([1, 2, 2, 3]).is_first()
Out[9]:
shape: (4,)
Series: '' [bool]
[
        false
        false
        true
        false
]
```